# correct JSON format from Jquery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm working on a project coding PHP-AJAX-Jquery and JSON and need to send the information of a form that has three input fields to a php file that will store the info of the three fields in the database.

my problem is that I need(I have because of project spec) to use Jquery-AJAX and JSON and I think I'm passing in a malformed JSON string to the PHP file, this is the js that is supposed to handle the call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ID_formulario').on('submit',function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();    
    var nombre = $('input#ID_nombre');
    var email = $('input#ID_email');

    if(validaForm(nombre, email)){

       var url = $(this).attr('action');
       var data = $(this).serializeArray();
       var type = $(this).attr('method');
       alert(data); 

        $.ajax({
               url:url,
               data:data,
               type:type,
               cache: false,
               contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
               dataType: 'json',

               beforeSend: function () {
               $("#flash").show();
               $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="imagen.gif" align="absmiddle"> <span class="loading">Realizando peticion...</span>');
               },

               error: function(){
               alert("error petición ajax");
               },

               success: function(datos){
               $('#result').empty().html(respuesta). fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut();
               $('#ID_formulario')[0].reset();
               $('input#ID_nombre').focus();
               $("#flash").hide();      
               //$("#display").after(html);
               //$("#result").append(data);
               }

               });
    }
});
});
```

my questions are: how to send the info of the three fields in a valid JSON format to the php file? is there any jquery function that helps? or is serializeArray() enough?

2. It's okay to use success: function(datos) or should I replace it to .done(function)) ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: you aren't passing json to php at all. `success:` is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to send anything as JSON to PHP. Just send it with type: POST and read it in PHP. Then return it as JSON to read in Javascript. You just read the $_POST in PHP. I believe you've mistaken your project specs and you need to RETURN data from PHP as JSON.

This is one of my projects:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
    var data = {
        "action": "product"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "response.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $(".the-return").html(
                  // Read returned JSON. Exammple
                "<div class='data-row'><strong>TYPE</strong> " + data["title"]+ "</div>";
            );
        }
    });
    return false;
   });
});
```

In PHP you take the POST and read data.

response.php

```
if (is_ajax()) {
  if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
        case "product": sendValues(); 
            break;
    }
  }
}


// Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

// Do everything with $_POST's here
function sendValues(){
  $return = $_POST; 
  $return["title"] = 'Something';    
  $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
  echo json_encode($return); // Return JSON formatted data to Javascript.
}
```

Comment: Thanks...So I don't need to send the info in the JSON format("name": "value")? the serialize() is enough?  I just found the JSON.encode(mydata) function, should I use it or still not necessary? another question, in your code what happens if the call: if (is_ajax()) {    is false?

Comment: No. You can send everything in your form using the $_POST method. You can read each input value as $_POST['input-name'] and read that in PHP with the jQuery AJAX request. Then you return those values as JSON to Javascript and print them out if need be, or as you said, just save the data in PHP to your DB and print out stuff like 'Success!'

Comment: If is_ajax() returns false, the script wont execute sendValues() and you wont get a successful ajax request in your js.

Comment: Wow, thak you so so much, one last question, is there a better way to manipulate the data received fromthe php file instead of data["title"], I mean, like the OOP way?

Comment: It depends solely on the purpose on what you intend on achieving with the form and the response. You can, if you like, create an object using the form, taking the response data, but it depends on your purpose.